# SSRS IIF statement issue

Tags: sql, variables, reporting-services, reporting

Trying to figure out why my IIF statement is not populating anything, and I'm sure it's something incorrect.  I am trying to display a row only if the Team is "A Team" and the StatusID is 10, and here is the expression.

```
=iif((Fields!Team.Value="A Team") and (Fields!StatusID.Value=10), True,False)
```

Comment: Since you are most likely setting the `Hidden` property of a row, shouldn't the `True` and `False` be reversed?

Comment: Even when reversed nothing happens.

Comment: The expression is fine and can be confirmed against a simple dataset... I would suggest it's either applied in the wrong place i.e. not in the Row -> Hidden property, or you're data is not what you're expecting.

Comment: Where you are using this `iif` statement? On a textbox or row or column or tablix or..? On the expression, hidden property or ..?

Comment: I am using it in the row's hidden property. It will lead to another issue, because I will think I will eventually need to use a parameter, but I need to get this one done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS is case sensitive. Try this
`=iif((UCASE$(Fields!Team.Value) LIKE "A%TEAM") and (Fields!StatusID.Value=10), True,False)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=iif((Fields!Team.Value LIKE "%A%") and (Fields!StatusID.Value=10), True,False)
```

If that works try taking off the wildcards one by one and see if that still works or adding Team and the space, it could be the spacing or formating of the Team.

Comment: It is still pulling everything, and if I reverse it to False,True it displays nothing (using in the hidden property)

Comment: Did you try adding more test between the Wildcards?
Perhaps something like 

      =iif((Fields!Team.Value LIKE "%A Te%") and (Fields!StatusID.Value=10), True,False)

Comment: I did, and the same result happened.